# counting numbers wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, numbers

I've encountered a strange problem.

I have saved a "current running" clip on my server, then send the id of the next or previous clip to determine if i need to skip forward or backward.

```
if ((request.command.substring(15) > device.currentClip)) {
            console.log("XXXXX command: " + request.command.substring(15));
            console.log("XXXXX current clip " + device.currentClip);
            console.log("[INFO] skipping forward (playlist)");
            return;
}  else if ((request.command.substring(15) < device.currentClip)) {
            console.log("XXXXX command: " + request.command.substring(15));
            console.log("XXXXX current clip " + device.currentClip);
            console.log("[INFO] skipping backward (playlist)");
            return;
}
```

Strangely, numbers over 10 are evaluated incorrectly, even though the console shows that they are received as they are meant to.

Why is that? Could it have something to do with wrong types? i expect them to be auto-typed or at least throw an error. but they just seem to be "wrong".

Console (always clicking skip-forward button):

```
'goto: clip id: 12'
XXXXX command: 12
XXXXX current clip 11
[INFO] skipping forward (playlist)
'goto: clip id: 10'
XXXXX command: 10
XXXXX current clip 9
[INFO] skipping backward (playlist)
```

Can someone explain the (possible) error?

Comment: Can you also print the whole `request.command` between quotes:  `console.log("'"+request.command+"'");`? Perhaps you have a space somewhere that triggers the behaviour.

Comment: updated the console output with request.command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substring()` returns a string, and comparisons on strings are done by comparing character by character, thus:

- "10" < "9", and
- "10" < "11"

You can use the `parseInt` function and convert both sides to `int` (if `device.currentClip` is already an `int` you don't need to convert it too):

```
var intCommand = parseInt(request.command.substring(15), 10);
var intCurrentClip = parseInt(device.currentClip);
if (intCommand > intCurrentClip)) {
// the rest of the code
```